# Qt UI получить кнопку из дизайнера

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть класс `MainWindow` (окно) и `User`. В классе окна есть `ui`. Я делал интерфейс через дизайнер, так что все элементы получаю с помощью `ui->...`
Но мне нужно получить, например кнопку, в файле с функцией `main`. Как вариант было сделать `ui` публичной переменной, но не помогло. Дело в том, что мне нужно связать кнопку и слот класса `User` с помощью `connect`.

Comment: Передать указатель на User в конструктор класса окна и там сделать connect?

Comment: Помогло)) Спасибо))